# Is it possible to use the WPF version of the Client Composite UI Application Block (CAB) for WinForms application

Tags: wpf, winforms, client, cab

I am at the initial stage of designing a client application. However, being new to WPF and having already gained some experience in Win forms development, time pressures on the project means that there is a risk to going down the WPF route. If time were no pressure, then I would say forget forms and design with WPF. However, I am not lucky enough to have this luxury. Having spent a little time investigating the Composite Application Block for Forms, I have decided that I will definitely develop the application within this framework. However, there are 2 versions of the CAB, 1 for WinForms that targets the .Net 2.0 runtime which has now been retired, and then the WPF version which targets .Net 3.5. Not being a fan of 'retired' code libraries, I would prefer to use the WPF version of CAB. This may be a silly question, but is it possible to use the WPF version of CAB for Win forms application developement? I do envisage at some point in the future moving to towards WPF. If I could use the WPF version  of CAB I am hoping that this would make it easier to migrate the forms application to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [somebody](http://www.softinsight.com/bnoyes/2008/10/13/CompositeExtensionsForWindowsForms.aspx) had the same idea that you did.

I found it by reading [this thread](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=33986) on the CompositeWPF codeplex forum, discussing this very issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without too many issues. We are currently using CAB to enable us to display SQL Reporting Services reports in WPF (along with a couple other items). It's a pretty simple implementation, but our architecture is WPF-based, not WinForms. As far as we've been able to tell, there wouldn't be much of a problem were it the other way around, and displaying both types of forms is done the same way.